# Plugin to see the relationships between tables

Tags: java, eclipse

I connect to database by using the graphical interface of eclipse itself through database explorer and in the database explorer i can see the database and tables also but in tables there are many primary and foreign key relationships , Please advise any plugin which I can install in eclipse by which I can see the graphically the relationships between the tables and how they are connected with each other..!

Folks Please advise for the plugin.I am using IBM db2 as database, and front end connecting with eclipse

Comment: if you use Oracle as underlying database, you could have a look to [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html). The only one I know.

Comment: You could also have a look to [AmaterasERD](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasERD). But I do not have experience with that. They say they do only provide `hsqldb`, but it looks like they already have a newer version and maybe they provide more dbs now. I would just give it a try ;)